# Discord, Mention someone when gets a role

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

Is there a way to mention someone immediately after getting a specific role in a specific channel?
For example when I, or any other admin, give someone a specific role the bot mentions them in a specific channel.

Here is my code:

```js
client.on("guildMemberUpdate", (oldMember, newMember) => {
    const channel = client.channels.cache.get("channelid");

    // If the role(s) are present on the old member object but no longer on the new one (i.e role(s) were removed)
    const removedRoles = oldMember.roles.cache.filter((role) => !newMember.roles.cache.has("roleid"));
    if (removedRoles.size > 0) console.log(`The roles ${removedRoles.map((r) => r.name)} were removed from ${oldMember.displayName}.`);
    // If the role(s) are present on the new member object but are not on the old one (i.e role(s) were added)
    const addedRoles = newMember.roles.cache.filter((role) => !oldMember.roles.cache.has("roleid"));
    if (addedRoles.size > 0) {
        if (newMember.roles.cache.some((role) => role.name === "testing")) {
            let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed().setTitle("♡﹕welcome!").setDescription("lalalala").setColor("#FFB6C1").setThumbnail("https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/806974794461216813/817737054745526304/giffy_2.gif");
            channel.send(`Welcome ${oldMember.user}`, embed);
        }
        console.log(`The roles ${addedRoles.map((r) => r.name)} were added to ${oldMember.displayName}.`);
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you show the code you've tried and the error?

Comment: I edited, I got no errors but it doesn't do anything

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with discordjs, but I assume there would be some kind of member update event equivalent and you can get a channel by id and send it there

Answer (score 0):

This is assuming your code is *exactly* as shown in the question, and not using placeholder strings.

Firstly, `"roleid"` should be `role.id` without the `""` when you're filtering. This will filter it properly, as should `channelId` where channel is defined, which I'm guessing are placeholders, but just in case.

Secondly, you'll probably want to check using `addedRoles.has("roleIdToSend")` as opposed to `newMember.roles.cache.some()`. This will DM them every time they're updated if they have the role, not if they only just got the role on that update.

Lastly, assuming you're using discord.js v13, you'll need to correct your `send()` method. It should look something like

```js
channel.send({
  content: `Welcome, ${oldMember.toString()}`,
  embeds: [embed]
});
```